# Python - How to determine hierarchy level of parsed XML elements?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, hierarchy

I am trying to parse elements with certain tag from XML file with Python and generate output excel document, which would contain elements and also preserve their hierarchy.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how deeply nested each element (over which parser iterates) is.

XML sample extract (3 elements, they can be nested arbitrarily within themselves):

```
<A>
   <B>
      <C>
      </C>
   </B>
</A>
<B>
    <A>
    </A>
</B>
```

Following code, using ElementTree, worked well to iterate over elements. But I think ElementTree is not capable determining how deeply each element is nested. See below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.parse('XML_file.xml')
tree = root.getroot()
for element in tree.iter():
    if element.tag in ("A","B","C"):
        print(element.tag)
```

This will get me the list of elements A,B,C in right order. But I need to print them out with information of their level,

So not only:

```
A
B
C
B
A
```

But something like:

```
A
--B
----C
B
--A
```

To be able to do this, I need to get the level of each element. Is there any suitable parser for python which can easily do this? I would imagine something like "element.hierarchyLevel" which would return some Integer index...

Comment: You need to employ some form of stack. Encounter an open tag, push it on the stack, closing tag, pop it. That way, the stack length will always contain the nesting level.

Comment: Note that you almost certainly want to import `xml.etree.cElementTree`, which is many times faster and 100% compatible with the pure-python module.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using a recursive function, that keeps track of your "level".

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def perf_func(elem, func, level=0):
    func(elem,level)
    for child in elem.getchildren():
        perf_func(child, func, level+1)

def print_level(elem,level):
    print '-'*level+elem.tag

root = ET.parse('XML_file.xml')
perf_func(root.getroot(), print_level)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solved it in very pretty way, will update the question with solution (+ one tiny correction)

Comment: Is there a way to add current values next to the tag?

Comment: How to save the output of this function to a list?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [xml.sax.saxhandler](http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.sax.handler.html):

```
import xml.sax as sax
import xml.sax.handler as saxhandler

class TreeBuilder(saxhandler.ContentHandler):
    # http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.handler.html#contenthandler-objects
    def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        print('--'*self.level + name)
        self.level += 1
    def endElement(self, name):
        self.level -= 1

builder = TreeBuilder()
src = '''\
<root>
<A>
   <B>
      <C>
      </C>
   </B>
</A>
<B>
    <A>
    </A>
</B>
</root>
'''
sax.parseString(src, builder)
```

yields

```
root
--A
----B
------C
--B
----A
```

Comment: Using SAX seems clever, but might stick to Schoolboy's idea.Thanks a lot for your help anyway!