# Visualizing XML children in Python using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, tree, elementtree, hierarchical

Given the XML:

```
<Anthology>
    <Price></Price>
    <Book>
        <Price></Price>
        <Leaflet>
            <Title>War</Title>
            <Price>20</Price>
        </Leaflet>
        <Leaflet>
            <Title>Peace</Title>
            <Price>30</Price>
        </Leaflet>
    </Book>
    <Book>
        <Price>60</Price>
    </Book>
</Anthology>
```

I would like to update the 'price' tags in a hierarchical manner and print:

> Anthology price: **110**,
>     Book 1 price: **50**,
>     Book 2 price: **60**

Or in pseudo speak, I would like to search an index item and have its 'price' tag reflect the sum of all the children 'price' tags.

Any suggestions how to attack this using ElementTree?

Comment: are you using the package lxml or regular the xml?

Comment: have you tried anything? [the doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is pretty explanatory.

Comment: BorrajaX, using the cElementTree module. Salman, working with this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15748897 I will post an update as I go.